# how to install ubuntu during boot up

Tags: installation, boot

I'm trying to install ubuntu but bloody windows is making it difficult (Most of my programs stopped working after windows downloaded an update).  I tried to install ubuntu when the computer start up, even pressing f8 but it keeps going to windows.

Comment: Can you please explain in more detail, your question is confusing ...

Comment: Are you sure the key you need is F8? What is your laptop brand? Find your laptop in this list: http://en.kioskea.net/faq/4178-laptops-access-bios-settings-key to know the key.

Answer (score 0):

First, check that the button you are using to choose the boot media is the right one. Your computer's manual should be able to tell you what button it is. Alternatively, change the boot order in BIOS to first boot from the removable media you are using. You should be aware that some older BIOS-versions are unable to boot from a USB-drive and you need to use a CD/DVD.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get into your system's BIOS, and change boot order.  Here are some of the keys that might get you into the BIOS, <kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F9,</kbd> , and <kbd>Del</kbd>.

Some systems will allow you to press <kbd>F9</kbd> to display a boot selection menu.  So once you have your bootable CD/DVD of USB, change the boot order, anf that will allow you to boot form the choosen media.  For more information on how to install Ubuntu, or on how to create a bootable media, see [Install Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest).

By the way <kbd>F8</kbd> , will display the Windows boot menu.

Answer (score 0):

The way I installed Ubuntu was 1) created a bootable thumb drive 2) booted from thumb drive (using the BIOS) 3) installed/formated the hard disk from the thumb.

Alternatively, you may want to use the bootable thumb to retrieve your files before you wipe the computer. Ubuntu requires a different file system than windows and your files will probably be lost.

Hope this helps.